# Change CurrentValue of a key press

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

I was wondering if there is a way that I could change the value of a key press such as <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, etc. Normally, when nothing is pressed, the `CurrentValue` will return `False`. My hope is that I might be able to change these values to `True` with some sort of controller. For example, it would be great if I could use a check box to tell *Mathematica* that <kbd>Shift</kbd> was depressed when it was not, but I understand that this is unlikely as these values are protected and probably fairly low level to change.

Intuitively, I would say it can't be done, but was just hoping that by some chance it would be possible.

Comment: May I ask if there is any context or you just want to know? (just like me now :))

Comment: Well, I'm attempting to make it possible to interact with a 3D Graphic using just a touchpad, and would like to be able to include the ability to Zoom and Pan. If Mathematica believes that the value of these keys are true, then these interactions can be done simply using the touchpad. Mathematica doesn't recognize touch gestures from my touchpad, and I cannot find a program to remap gestures like Pinch to Zoom that supports the Logitech device I'm using. @Kuba

Comment: I suppose I'm really just trying to simulate a key press in some way. Any ideas? By the way, I'll be running this on a Mac in the end, if it makes any difference.

Comment: If you are making your own guis, you could simply make a wrapper function for `CurrentValue`, which defaults to the current key state, but is overwritten by your button actions. As for simulating key presses, I'm not even sure that Mathematica actually uses the values of `CurrentValue` as opposed to keeping it's keyboard/mouse interface in logic seperate to the user exposed front-end stuff.

Comment: @jVincent The idea of a wrapper sounds like it could work. Could you possibly supply an example of how to do this, or point me to an explanation of how to override the default value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to get other code to think shift is depressed, but just want a sort of override in your own interfaces, you can create a wrapper function and just change it's values. For instance a very simple example would be:

```
myCurrentValue[a___] := CurrentValue[a]
Checkbox[Dynamic[shiftdown, 
   (shiftdown = #; 
      If[#,
      myCurrentValue["ShiftKey"] = True,
      myCurrentValue["ShiftKey"] =.
      ]
   )&
]]

Dynamic@MyCurrentValue["ShiftKey"]
```

This will however naturally only work in code that then call your wrapper and not on stuff relying directly on `CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]`.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. This won't work for the Graphic because it relies on the actual value of `"ShiftKey"`, not `myCurrentValue`. So you don't believe that there is any way to make keyboard-free panning, for example, work short of remapping some mouse or touch pad gesture? @jVincent

Comment: @Matt You are somewhat right, but I'm not even sure that the frontend actually uses `CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]` for panning. For all we know, the panning and zooming could be behind the scenes magic that's not in any way related to the Mathematica code except through it's interaction with the `Viewpoint` and `ViewAngle` option of the graphics. You could write your own interface code using `EventHandler` and those settings to allow for your custom behavior, but it won't work in arbitrary graphics unless they are created with your panzoom-er additions then.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks. @jVincent

Comment: @Matt care to share your solution? You could append it to your answer for others to draw use from.